# Determine Max System Video Memory

Tags: memory, gpu

I have a video card installed, which is: "Radeon RX 580 ARMOR 8G" (so, 8G of VRAM)

I have confirmed the 8G amount by running a program that allocates increasing amounts of texture memory, and I can see performance dives at 8G, presumably due reaching that limit (it does not fail though, presumably due to overcommit via the driver).

So, I am confident that my card does indeed have 8G of memory (:

However, I cannot seem to find that number by querying my hardware.

From `lspci -v`, I see:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] (rev e7) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (Radeon RX 580 Armor 4G OC)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 85
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    ...
```

There are a few pieces of information relating to memory, but none of them say 8G:

- "Radeon RX 580 Armor 4G OC" — I don't know where this comes from, but maybe it is a generic name for this card that the driver uses?

  - Interstingly, the first line says "Radeon RX 470/480" when the card is actually a 580, so there is clearly some generalization going on here...
- "prefetchable... 256M" — This looks like a real memory statistic, but does not come anywhere near 8G.

Is there somewhere else I should be looking for this information?

Is this information made available through Linux, or does it require some vendor-specific tool?

Aside: I'm running Debian, if that matters.